# How to get started with hardware interface programming?

Tags: hardware

I have been doing desktop programming for a while but want to get started with interfacing with hardware. Specifically, I would like to learn how to use serial ports to take an external event and alert my application (so for example, I can turn on a camera when motion is detected by an external sensor). 
Please tell me how to get started, what type of sensors, what books (or online resources) are available. I tried Bing and Google but I need more pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Serial interfaces are fairly simple to work with.  But they do require some sort of a decoder on the other end (such as a [UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UART).)  Another option would be using the [parellel port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port).  The advantage of using a parallel port is you start with a break out of the I/O pins.  You can typically control 8 devices with a very simple to build interface.

Most platforms gave a simple way to gain access to the LPT ports without too much effort and again they are very easy to interface.

**Quick results for tutorials...**

- [Parallel Port Programming](http://electrosofts.com/parallel/)
- [Parallel port output circuit](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/parallel_output.html)
- [A tutorial on Parallel port interfacing](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/A_tutorial_on_Parallel_port_Interfacing.html)

**LPT Port Info...**

- [Parallel Port (PC)](http://www.hardwarebook.info/Parallel_%28PC%29)
- [LapLink Cable](http://www.hardwarebook.info/LapLink/InterLink_Parallel)
- [Printer Cable](http://www.hardwarebook.info/Printer)
- [IEEE 1284-B](http://www.hardwarebook.info/IEEE1284-B)
- [IEEE 1284-C](http://www.hardwarebook.info/IEEE1284-C)
- [Centronics (36 pin)](http://www.hardwarebook.info/Centronics)

Comment: Computers nowadays don't have parallel ports. Do they?

Comment: Most don't but this post in 7 years old and you can still use these patterns with `USB to LPT` devices.  Better still there are now hundreds of options to do this without LPT.  https://www.amazon.com/s/?field-keywords=usb+gpio+module

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you the book [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

Although I haven't programmed any hardware interface yet, I think this book will get you ready to start hacking.

Answer (score 1):

There really aren't a lot of one-size-fits-all tips for this.  You're going to need to look at the documentation for your device, it should specify the protocol of what it will send over the serial port and what commands you can send in return.

Make sure you understand things like what means to have a text encoding like ASCII or UTF8.  Most any device that sends and expects text will use an ASCII encoding.

I'm not sure what OS or language you're using, but be aware that you're sending raw binary data through a serial port, so for example if you're using C# you would want to wrap your serial port data stream with a StreamWriter or StreamReader with the correct text encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find an old modem online or craigslist that might be a good start.  The serial comms specs for those are pretty well documented.

After that I would just start investigating things that you are interested in - your interest in the project will drive the learning and progress more than anything IMO.

I think this site has some fun things to try:

http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/

Answer (score 0):

You should get a data acquisition hardware and interface with that.

http://www.dataq.com/products/hardware/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to learn how to use the serial port, get another PC with HyperTerminal (included free with Windows), and use it to send and receive data from your development machine over the serial port.  This will give you very manual control over what's sent to your development box, so you can get some confidence that what you're reading and writing is correct.  Once you've got the basics of serial I/O down, you can move on to your camera/motion sensor/etc.

You don't mention what OS or development environment you're using, but in VS 2005/.NET 2.0, there is actually a SerialPort class.  If you're doing raw Windows API, MSDN has an article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx which covers the basics.  If you're using another OS, sorry I'm not that familiar (I know, boo hiss on me).

The most important thing is just remember to set your communication parameters on both sides of the connection the same.  There are four parameters that govern if both sides can understand each other : baud rate, bits-per-byte (usually 8), parity bits (even parity, odd parity, none, or always 1 or 0), and stop bits.  HyperTerminal also lists a "Flow Control" option, I recommend setting it to "None" until you get comfortable.  Xon/Xoff flow control is a fairly common way of making the other side pause while you process a bufferfull of data.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a microcontroller and build a simple robot, cnc mill or something. Atmel AVR and/or PIC is the most common from what i understand.

Also gives a lot of electronics experience